# Not filled the required fields, php is executed

Tags: php, ajax, field, required

I have html form with input fields. Data from the form will be sent throght the ajax function in php and php returns the result in html.
Although not all fields are filled php executes and returns the result.
If all fields are filled not get a result from php.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="inputform">
    <form>  
        Name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="firstname" required><br>
        Surname:<br>
        <input type="text" id="lastname" required ><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick='ajax()'>
        <div id="ajaxDiv"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function ajax() {
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try {
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e) {
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
        var answer = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
        answer.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
};

var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;


var queryString = "?firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "test.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);}
```

php

```
<?php
$firstname=$_GET['firstname'];
$lastname=$_GET['lastname'];
echo $firstname;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use ajax to send form data to server and you call method `ajax()` on form submit. So, there is no need in `<form>` tag, because when you click on button, you call `ajax()` function and form is submitting automatically.

Remove `<form>` and change:
`<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick='ajax()'>`
to
`<input type="button" value="submit" onclick='ajax()'>`

Comment: Thanks for fast answer.

Without <form> tag and type="submit", when I click on submit I'm not receiving notification that a field is not filled.

Comment: How do you want to send data to server? Asynchronously or? If asynchronously, then you should use ajax and remove form tag, otherwise you need to remove ajax and use form tag `method="get"`.